# How to view cookies set by google chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm working on a google chrome extension which has a button and a popup-overlay. Inside this extension, I set and remove cookies for the user. During development, the extension is making requests to localhost:8080 and (I assume) cookies are being set with localhost as the domain.

The problem is, I can't figure out how to view these cookies in a list from within Chrome. Firefox has a simple feature for viewing all the cookies set by various hostnames and Chrome appears to as well (although I'm less familiar with the developer tools in Chrome). But in Chrome's cookie list, I can't find any cookies set for localhost, nor any cookies for my extension, whatsoever. I've tried a few 3rd party cookie extensions too -- no luck there either.

Will cookies set by extensions appear in the same place as cookies set by normal websites? If so, why am I not seeing them? Help appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Yes they appear in sample place.. I have written a sample extension for demonstration; Screen shot taken after testing this for developer.chrome.com domain

[image]

Sample Extension:

***manifest.json***

```
{
  "name" : "Cookie API Demo",
  "version" : "1",
  "description" : "This is demonstration of Cookie API",
  "permissions": [ "cookies","<all_urls>"],
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "screen.png",
    "default_popup":"popup.html"
  },
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

***popup.html***

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="popup.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

***popup.js***

```
function cookieinfo(){
    chrome.cookies.getAll({},function (cookie){
        console.log(cookie.length);
        for(i=0;i<cookie.length;i++){
            console.log(JSON.stringify(cookie[i]));
        }
    });
    chrome.cookies.getAllCookieStores(function (cookiestores){
        for(i=0;i<cookiestores.length;i++){
            console.log(JSON.stringify(cookiestores[i]));
        }
    });
    chrome.cookies.set({"name":"Sample1","url":"http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/cookies.html","value":"Dummy Data"},function (cookie){
        console.log(JSON.stringify(cookie));
        console.log(chrome.extension.lastError);
        console.log(chrome.runtime.lastError);
    });
    chrome.cookies.onChanged.addListener(function (changeInfo){
        console.log(JSON.stringify(changeInfo));
    });
}
window.onload=cookieinfo;
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I figured it out. It's a forehead slapper, but I'll post the answer here anyway in case others need help.

The cookies for the overlay extension only show up in the "developer tools" if you inspect the overlay element. That is, if you close the overlay and click the wrench button, developer tools, resources, cookies, the only thing you'll see there are cookies for the underlying page.

In order to see cookies for an overlay extension, right-click INSIDE the overlay and "inspect element". The cookies do show up there, and the "domain" they're attached to is the extension's unique id (kackjckjckjckcjckjckcjkcjckcj or what-have-you).

Random note: At the time of this writing, the Jquery cookies plugin always kills your cookies at session, no matter what you set the expiration to. In order to get my cookies to persist (survive) beyond browser close, I had to include good old-fashioned setCookie() and getCookie() functions and get rid of Jquery cookies.

Answer (score -1):

In your browser - visit:

```
chrome://settings/cookies
```

I just set it as the address for a bookmark in chrome - and then just click my bookmark when I want to see the cookies